# Use pxfonts in listings only

Tags: fonts, listings

I really like the [`pxfont`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pxfonts) package for displaying code in listings. I would usually just do this to load `pxfont` for the entire document;
`\usepackage{pxfonts}`.

However, this time I am required to use a template with mandatory fonts for the text. I would still like to use pxfonts for the code listings, but can not set it globally, as it would overwrite the mandatory non-listings font settings.

Is there any way to isolate the usage of pxfonts to listings only? I have tried various combinations of `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand` to 'capture' the font settings, reset them to default, and use the captured version to set the listings' basicstyle. Sadly, I lack the experience and I didn't get anything working.

Any ideas?

Comment: It should be possible, but you should add, how the listings should be printed: only in set in `\ttfamily` or in the default way `listings` works? Side remark: Very, very recently a new package `newpx` was published “meant to be a replacement for Young Ryu’s `pxfonts`”.

Comment: If you mean the typewriter font coming with `pxfonts`, it's a matter of saying `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pxtt}` in your preamble.

Comment: @agreg thanks for the suggestion! I didn't know I could do that without including the pxfonts package. It's not perfect, as it's still a document-wide substitution, but it's certainly a solution for the document I'm working on now. Thanks!

Comment: @peanutman It's certainly possible to "localize" that effect, but you should be more explicit about your needs.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you need of PXfonts is the typewriter type font, then

```
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pxtt}
```

in the preamble will tell LaTeX to use it instead of the default.

If you need the font only inside `lstlisting` environments, the easiest solution is to say

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\fontfamily{pxtt}\selectfont}
```